# Displaying a point on another series in Highcharts (without flags)

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts instance [1] with 4 series. Two of the series are index/ratio series and two are raw value series. What I would like to do is display the raw value series points on one of the index series without converting the raw value series to 'flags'. The reason for this is that I want all my point values to be in one tooltip.

With respect to the attached jsfiddle I would like the center buy and sell points to appear on the 'Price Change' series and for the current tooltip behavior in the example to be unchanged. I want one tooltip with four values and for the buy/sell values to be their raw values instead of the 'y' value of where they are displayed.

Is that something that is doable with Highcharts/Highstock?

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/eZL8e/
```

Dave

Comment: What is the "raw values" of the buy/sell point? You have it set up like `data: [[1374555600000, 21.13],...]` The y-value is the raw value, yes?

Comment: @wergeld Yes - the y-value is what I meant by "raw".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily manipulate what you want to display in tooltip using `pointFormat` for each series. Then you can change fromat for point from `[timestamp, value]` to `{x: timestamp, y: value, myProperty: exValue}`. Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/eZL8e/5/

For buys:

```
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.raw}</b><br/>'   
            },
            data: [
                {x: 1374555600000, raw: 21.13, y: 75},
                {x: 1374642000000, raw: 20.5753, y: 85},
                {x: 1374728400000, raw: 20.9367, y: 63}
            ]
```

Note: There is only one limitation for that solution, you need to disable `dataGrouping`, since grouped point's doesn't have custom properties like `raw`.